# Is there any positional correlation between two entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, particle-detectors

According to this article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment, under "The Experiement" the experiment only makes sure that the two particles hit the detector but does not mention that the XY position of the particles is measured.  Has anybody done this and ... observed any similarities by where they are detected or is the position random?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? They are measured at positions where the detectors are located. And they follow normal laws each particle independently.

Comment: I'm trying to create an experiment for an idea in which I need to be able to calculate position and time to a high degree of accuracy, but current equipment is far too coarse for the accuracy I need to demonstrate that my hypothesized events are not random noise.  I'm trying to determine if entangled particles can solve some of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really entangle particles such that the composite system has a "total position" that must remain "conserved" when you subsequently measure the particle positions separately. So, no, I don't think anybody's done anything like this. But maybe there's some clever way to prepare entangled particles with respect to some observable, such that the preparation procedure also guarantees correlation between that observable and position. I'm neither sure whether that's possible or provably impossible.

Comment: When you say "you can't....", do you mean "can't" in theory or in practice?

Comment: @WillO, he is saying there is no current way to guarantee position and it's probably impossible to do it in practice, unless there is some, yet to be discovered way, to create entangled particles that way.

Comment: @WillO In theory, mostly, though I'm no expert in this (or, for that matter, much of any:) area. For example, position (or momentum,energy,etc) are pretty much continuous unless you've got boundary conditions constraining your system within a small well,box,whatever. And two component systems, measured such that the measurement events are spacelike separated, are likely pretty far apart. And I'm not familiar with entangling observables in a continuous region of their spectrum. Do you know if that's possible?